# Python Replace part of text in text file

Tags: python, text, replace

Current Text file:

```
NAME  S1  2581751 2581758       1            
NAME  S2  2581761 2581776       1               
NAME  S3  2581779 2581786       1      
NAME  S4  2581789 2581804       1        
NAME  S5 2581807 2581814       1           
C       A0-ABC          
    A(1) =   0.1518     !k2            
    B(2) =   0.4910     !K2O         
    C(3) =   0.0314     !D2       
    D(4) =   0.0876     !CO          
    E(5) =   0.2382     !C1        
C   CI-ABC                 
NAME  S5  2581779 2581786       1            
NAME  S5  2581789 2581804       1          
NAME  S5  2581807 2581814       1
```

Updated Text file will look like:

```
NAME  S1  2581751 2581758       1            
NAME  S2  2581761 2581776       1               
NAME  S3  2581779 2581786       1      
NAME  S4  2581789 2581804       1        
NAME  S5 2581807 2581814       1           
C       A0-ABC          
    A(1) =   0.2145     !k2            
    B(2) =   0.542    !K2O         
    C(3) =   0.35     !D2       
    D(4) =   0.0476     !CO          
    E(5) =   0.123     !C1        
C   CI-ABC                 
NAME  S5  2581779 2581786       1            
NAME  S5  2581789 2581804       1          
NAME  S5  2581807 2581814       1
```

I would like to change number in text file (`0.1518`, `0.4910`...) to new number (`0.2145`, `0.5242`...), which shown in below. Initially, I take out the line between `C A0-ABC` and `C    CI-ABC` and save in list and then, update the numbers and save it as different name. But I have problem to replace the updated number into original text file.

```
import sys
import os
import numpy as np             
import math          
import string 

path='Directory..'                                                              
k2 =0.2145
K2O=0.542
D2 = 0.35
CO = 0.476
C1 = 0.123
Update=[str(k2),str(K2O),str(D2),str(CO),str(C1)]
files = os.listdir('.')
f = open(path+'\Input.txt','r')
lines = f.readlines()
copy = False
save_list=[]
for line in lines :
    if line.strip() == "C  A0-ABC":
       copy = True
    elif line.strip() == "C CI-ABC":
       copy = False
    elif copy:
       save_list.append(line)

 file= open(path+'\Update_INPF.txt','w')
 lis=[x.split() for x in save_list]
 A = [str(x[0]) for x in lis]
 B = [str(x[1]) for x in lis]
 C = Update
 D= [str(x[3]) for x in lis]
 F=zip(A,B,C,D)

 for x in list(F):
     file.write("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\n".format(*x))
 file.close()
 print save_list
```

Comment: Any advance on *"I have problem"*?

Comment: The "I have a problem" error inherits from the more general "Doesn't work" error.  Check the type on the error to see if your problem is physical, mental or spiritual.

Answer (score 0):

```
path = 'Directory..'                                                              

k2 = 0.2145
K2O = 0.542
D2 = 0.35
CO = 0.476
C1 = 0.123

fold = open(path + '\Input.txt','r')
fnew = open(path + '\Update_INPF.txt','w')

for line in f.readlines():

    line = line.split()

    if line[0] == 'A(1)':
        newline =  ' '.join(line[:2] + [str[k2]] + line[-1])
    elif line[0] == 'B(2)':
        newline =  ' '.join(line[:2] + [str[K20]] + line[-1])
    elif line[0] == 'C(3)':
        newline =  ' '.join(line[:2] + [str[D2]] + line[-1])
    elif line[0] == 'D(4)':
        newline =  ' '.join(line[:2] + [str[C0]] + line[-1])
    elif line[0] == 'E(5)':
        newline =  ' '.join(line[:2] + [str[C1]] + line[-1])
    else:
        newline = line

    fnew.write(newline)

fold.close()
fnew.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments killantics. It works in my machine after modified slightly. I've got another question. My original text file is approx.400MB and I would like to change the text only between  "C  A0-ABC  and  C CI-ABC  due to that there are another A(1) B(2) C(3) D(4) in the text file. Would you please give me tips how I should do??  Thanks,